# Problem with using brain.js. How to solve the error?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I installed brianjs on my server. At startup it gives an error -
`Error: Module did not self-register: '/var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/gl/build/webgl.node'.`

When I use the npm rebuild command, a huge error appears:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/gl/build'
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/Float16ToFloat32.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/MemoryBuffer.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/angleutils.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/debug.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/mathutil.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/string_utils.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/tls.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/utilities.o
npm ERR!   AR(target) Release/obj.target/angle/src/angle_common.a
npm ERR!   COPY Release/angle_common.a
npm ERR!   COPY Release/obj/gen/angle/id/commit.h
npm ERR!   TOUCH Release/obj.target/angle/src/commit_id.stamp
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/common/event_tracer.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/AttributeMap.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Buffer.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Caps.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Compiler.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Config.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Context.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Data.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Debug.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Device.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Display.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Error.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Fence.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Framebuffer.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/FramebufferAttachment.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/gl/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.18.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.6 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! (node:1961) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/gl/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.18.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.18.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.18.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/gl',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp: In constructor ‘gl::HandleAllocator::HandleAllocator()’:
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:52: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:76: error: ‘::max’ has not been declared; did you mean ‘std::max’?
npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                                                            ^~~
npm ERR!       |                                                                            std::max
npm ERR! In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/algorithm:62,
npm ERR!                  from ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:12:
npm ERR! /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algo.h:3467:5: note: ‘std::max’ declared here
npm ERR!  3467 |     max(initializer_list<_Tp> __l, _Compare __comp)
npm ERR!       |     ^~~
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token
npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                           ^
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:52: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:73: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                                                         ^
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:76: error: ‘::max’ has not been declared; did you mean ‘std::max’?
npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                                                            ^~~
npm ERR!       |                                                                            std::max
npm ERR! In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/algorithm:62,
npm ERR!                  from ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:12:
npm ERR! /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algo.h:3467:5: note: ‘std::max’ declared here
npm ERR!  3467 |     max(initializer_list<_Tp> __l, _Compare __comp)
npm ERR!       |     ^~~
npm ERR! make: *** [angle/src/libANGLE.target.mk:241: Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-52-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/server-nodejs/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.18.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-10-21T17_49_10_284Z-debug-0.log
```

brian.js is the most problematic library I have ever installed. Help with a solution please

P.S. Do not read this text.. Stackoverflow thinks that I wrote little, but I can not add anything